# Compromised interoperability in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, f#

Recently I asked a question here about using F# extensions in C#. Brian quoted:

> Per the language spec, section 10.7 "Type extensions":
>
> Optional extension members are syntactic sugar for static members. Uses of optional extension members elaborate to calls to static members with encoded names where the object is passed as the first argument. The encoding of names is not specified in this release of F# and is not compatible with C# encodings of C# extension members.

I am wondering if there are any other interoperability issues in .NET that restricts the usage of some functionality to some languages but not others?

Answer (score 6):

I expect there are lots of things, but mostly in corner cases if you're talking about the major managed languages (C#, VB, and soon F#).  Other cases where F# currently interacts poorly with C# is when there method overloads that take both Action and Func (the C# overload resolution works differently than F#, so F# calls to such an API may be more verbose); 'params' argument arrays (especially when trying to tak advantage of 'array covariance', which is a feature of C# but not F#); there are some issues regarding subclassing or implementing interfaces, combined with accessibility (e.g. public versus internal), where sometimes you cannot derive an F# class from a C# one...

Many of these issues are simply either 'bugs' in the F# CTP compiler or 'design issues' with the F# language spec that may be changed before the final release of F#.

I don't know the dusty corners of the CLR well enough, but I bet that there are places where C# and VB fails to mesh.  And there are features of the CLR that none of the major languages use, so I expect there's ways to create valid IL that may cause problems with some interop.

Overall I think all this stuff is minor, and in the case of F#, a bit of it will be 'fixed' before the final release.  But I will be curious to see what other things people call out, as it could be useful feedback for the managed language teams at MS.

Comment: Here's one: Optional parameters in C# versus VB.

Answer (score 2):

There's a set of [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) released by Microsoft for dealing with this kind of thing. Basically it's for class designers, and includes suggestions such as not including methods which differ only by case (for case-insensitive languages like VB), providing alternate methods for for operators when operator overloading might not be available, etc.

Comment: Oops, the link disappeared.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I put the link for you.

Answer (score 2):

C++/CLI has "pass by value" semantics for CLR objects (not references, but objects themselves), complete with copy constructors, temporaries and their destruction, etc. You can write:

```
ref class Foo {
public:
  Foo() { ... }
  Foo(Foo% other) { ... }
};
```

and then:

```
Foo^ getFooRef() { ... } // returns a reference to Foo
Foo getFoo() { ... } // returns a copy of Foo
```

Of course, on CLR level it's all references - C++/CLI simulates copy semantics by calling constructors, `operator=`, and destructors at moments where you expect them to be called. In case of "return by value", it means that the caller will have to correctly destruct the object, reference to which it receives. Neither C#, nor VB, nor any other CLI language apart from C++/CLI know how to do it, so such methods aren't callable from them.

Another interesting bit is that CLR allows to define methods with `ref` return types. No CLR language supports them (not even C++/CLI), but you can hand-code one in MSIL, and it won't be callable from any other language.

In general, this sort of thing is precisely why Common Language Specification (CLS) was created. If you stick to its rules, you shouldn't have interoperability problem with any language.

Comment: Can a method safely return a `ref` to a variable stored in an object which was not pinned by the caller without risk that the GC will move the object between the time the method returns and the caller uses the `ref`?  If so, how would the CIL code let the GC know when the object could be moved?

Comment: `ref` are managed pointers, so GC is aware of them and will update them as needed when objects are moved around - that's precisely what makes them different from unsafe pointers.

Comment: When you say a "managed pointer", do you mean that a `ref` is actually an object reference plus an offset, or is there some other means via which the GC can take a ref and identify the object to which it prefers?  If a field is passed *into* a method by ref, metadata in the caller could take care of pinning the object, but I don't see how that could work in general with a ref that's returned via method.  Is there some other trick .NET can use for that?

Comment: No, it's just a regular pointer in terms of representation, but it's the one that is guaranteed to point somewhere inside the managed heap (or to the stack), and GC can assume that this guarantee holds. There's no pinning involved here at all - rather, when GC defragments the heap, it walks the stack and updates all object references and managed pointers to point to the new locations. It doesn't need to know which object the pointer being updated belongs to, because it can always find out by seeing if it is within the range of the corresponding memory block.

Comment: My understanding of the GC is that dead objects in the gen0 heap were not examined at all by the GC.  Instead, all live objects were moved to the gen1 heap and anything that wasn't pinned and wasn't live would become the new gen0 heap.  Does the GC walk all objects in a heap segment if any managed pointer exists to something within that segment, or how would that work?  It would seem that if the runtime did that, it would provide better support for returning byrefs; as it is, I can't think of anyplace where a method would have to be allowed to return a byref it didn't receive.

Comment: The reason why the runtime does not allow you to return byrefs freely is because they can reference value-type locals directly on the stack, which is something that GC doesn't deal with. As I recall, it's actually legal to return byref to an object field in CLR - the CLI spec does not consider it verifiable, but MS implementation does.

Comment: Eric Lippert has said that in his blog, but I don't see how it would work.  Given `int[] arr = new int[23]; doSomething(ref arr[0]);` the code which uses the byref knows that `arr` must be pinned until it's done with the byref.  If e.g. `List[T]` had a `ref T this[int index] { get {return ref _backingArray[index];}}`, given `doSomething(ref myList[0]);`, the object referenced by `_backingArray` would need to continue to be pinned as long as the byref existed, but the code using the byref would know nothing about what needed to be pinned.

Comment: To reiterate: byref doesn't pin anything. Byref works exactly the same as regular object references, in that they are updated as objects are moved around in memory.

Comment: I'm curious how that would work.  If a byref to a blittable object gets passed to unmanaged code, the object would certainly have to be pinned until the call returns, and I can't see any way that the system could locate the object associated with a byref without doing a heap walk (which would probably cost about as much as a GC) unless there were metadata somewhere associating the byref with the object from which it came.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I can see relocation could work if a local variable identifying the object into which the byref is taken had to remain in scope for the lifetime of the byref.  Do you know if the existence of a byref would be sufficient to keep an object alive even if no other reference exists to it, and what mechanism could be used to achieve that?

Comment: In CLR, the "pinned" modifier is applied to variables of pointer types, not to object references. So, really, an object is pinned if there is a pinned local somewhere on the stack that points inside that object. Since it really only matters for the GC, I would expect that the act of assigning to a pinned local does not actually do anything, but when GC happens, it walks the stack and identifies all pinned pointers first, and then when it does the heap walk, it checks every object against those pointers. So there's no "extra" walk necessary, and none happens if there is no GC.

Comment: That's what I was thinking ("upon further consideration"), but for that to work a stack walk would have to be able to identify the object into which the byref points.  If e.g. a `List<T>` indexer could return a byref into the backing array, would there be any way for the GC to identify the target of the byref once the indexer returned?  The code which used the indexer might keep a reference to the `List<T>` for the life of the byref, but there's no guarantee the `List<T>` wouldn't overwrite the only extant reference to the array if used in thread-unsafe fashion.

Comment: If you are already walking the objects, identifying the object from a byref is trivial - you know where on the heap the object is, and you know its length, so you just see if the byref points within that range. This would have to be done for all byrefs currently on the stack, but there normally aren't many even on deep stacks.

Comment: By my understanding, a normal GC doesn't examine most dead objects in gen0 or gen1--it copies all live objects and recycles all non-pinned memory from that generation.  If there isn't any case where legitimate Framework code would allow a byref to a heap object to outlive a rooted reference, supporting such usage would seem to add unnecessary complexity.  Maybe .NET does it, but it's hardly obvious that it does or should.

Answer (score 1):

*Consuming* f# classes *from c#* code can be tricky or annoying at times.

#### Events in f# are not 'normal' events by default

Adding the `[<CLIEvent>]` Attribute solves this but unless you use DelegateEvent rather than Event the [c# code must reference FSharpCore](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10554.aspx).

#### First Class function's differences

Making a delegate out of a FastFunc (the back bone of f#'s functions) in f# is easy.
Making a FastFunc from a delegate in c# is rather more annoying and is [touched on here](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/10/15/functional-c-implementing-async-computations-in-c.aspx). In particular the `Unit` concept maps very badly back into c# and the Func/Action delegate world.

#### Operators

Operators defined in f# are poorly, [and inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967508/f-and-operator-overloads), handled in other CLR languages. That is an inevitable result of the CLR not defining the sort of complex type meta data that would be required.
Operators should be considered language features and not expected to translate well between different languages. Any useful operator should have an equivalent static method that allows a consistent and portable means of accessing the functionality.

#### Type inference

In f# this is pervasive and as a result you may find some very complex types being constructed. Once used in c# this may become cumbersome since type inference on functions is not as powerful but worse it is entirely absent from constructors which can result in painfully verbose c# code.