# F# and Operator Overloads: (>) and (^)

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, static-typing

Ok, so can someone explain to me why F# allows you to overload the > and ^ operators, but doesn't allow you to use them?

```
+ (op_Addition): Works just fine.
^ (op_Concatenate): Compiler error in F#. Apparently only strings can be concatenated.
> (op_GreaterThan): Runtime Error – Failure during generic comparison: the type Program+OppTest4 does not implement the System.IComparable interface.
```

If I compile my F# code as a library and use those operators from VB, they all work. If I use those operators from C#, all but op_Concatenate work (as expected). But F# not only ignores some them, the static type checker doesn't even bother telling you that it plans on doing so.

**Edit** Code Sample

```
type OppTest4(value: int) =
   member this.value = value
   static member (^) (left : OppTest4, right : OppTest4) =
     OppTest4( Int32.Parse( left.value.ToString() ^ right.value.ToString()  ))
   static member (+) (left : OppTest4, right : OppTest4) =
     OppTest4(left.value + right.value )
   static member (>) (left : OppTest4, right : OppTest4) =
     left.value > right.value
   static member (<) (left : OppTest4, right : OppTest4) =
     left.value < right.value
```

Answer (score 4):

F# has default meanings for these operator symbols that's reasonable for F#.  You can always define your own meanings that shadow the defaults, a la

```
let (>) x y = ...
```

For example, you could define this operator to mean "T.operator>(U)" (assuming x has type T and y has type U).

See prim-types.fs in FSharp.Core in the source distribution for the default definitions.  (They are non-trivial!)

Given the combination of (1) lack of support for a type-class like mechanism on the CLR (for defining common semantics among a set of otherwise-unrelated types) and (2) the fact that primitive types (like 'int') often need to be special-cased for any programming language implementation (e.g. System.Int32 does not define an operator+ method, but most programming languages choose to behave as though such a method exists), it's hard to imagine any generally interoperable operator stuff across all languages on .Net today.  There are a lot of design-trade-offs depending on exactly what a language chooses to do (too many interacting issues to sum up here).  In any case, you should be able to call any method from F#, and if the default operator behaviors are undesirable, you can redefine (shadow) the operators to the behaviors you want.  If there's a particular scenario you have in mind that you're having trouble to make work, let me know.

EDIT

I added more detail at

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10869.aspx

Comment: Ok, then why doesn't this work? "static member (>) (left : OppTest4, right : OppTest4) =
     left.value > right.value"

Comment: > it's hard to imagine any generally interoperable operator stuff across all languages on .Net today. < But there is! If you use the code I show in my question, VB will honor all the operators. F# is emitting the standard IL code, it just isn't consuming it.

Comment: I'd be curious on whether I can shadow the default operator definition only for one type using a let binding - I don't have control over the type implementation. If so how would that be done?
I've tried let (>) (a:SomeType) (b:SomeType) = ... but then any comparison made between other types broke so that 2 > 1 didn't compile anymore.

Comment: @emaster, no you can't shadow just for one type.  All, if I can find a few hours to set aside over the next week, I'll try to blog about this, as there are a lot of different interacting forces at work.

Comment: In the meantime, someone else has posted a nice summary at http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10860.aspx

Comment: @Brian both of your links are dead =(

Answer (score 0):

I agree, there is inconsistency: operator can be defined, but can't be used.

Are you asking, why F# designers decided to implement comparison with System.IComparable interface rather than operators overload? I don't know why, but in OO language I would prefer IComparable rather than operators overloading. So, I would suggest to F# developers to break C# compatibility and forbid "static member (>) (...)" syntax sugar.

If you are asking how to call these overloaded operators it is pretty easy: use op_Concatenate, op_GreaterThan or op_LessThan static members. (Really, I've got a compiler warning, describing the problem. F# 1.9.6.16)

Runtime Error casting to System.IComparable without any compiler warning definitely is a bug. You can send it to fsbugs@microsoft.com.

Comment: The runtime error is not a bug, it is By Design.  I have not seen a public discussion of this design, however, which is well-motivated even if non-obvious, so I'll try to rectify that soon.

Comment: Ok, it is impossible to proof, that every instance of OppTest4 doesn't have IComparable interface.

But still it is known that there are OppTest4 instances that can't be cast to IComparable ! So there must be a warning at least! 
Why not?

Comment: @.vpolozov.name: it looks like section 9.6 of the F# spec (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec2.aspx) indicates that they're considering adding warnings in certain situations where use of the comparison operators is likely to fail.

Comment: @kvb it appears the link is dead =(